# Separate two rows in one column and display it in two columns

Tags: sql-server

I have one table 'Notes' and column name 'Note' with value of Hi and Hello
looks like this

```
Note
--------
HI
HELLO
```

I want to separate it in two column in sql
output would be like this:

```
Note1   Note2
------------------
Hi      Hello
```

How would i do it in sql query?

Comment: What if there are three rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This? It should work if there are more than 2 rows.

```
WITH    NotesWithId
AS      (
        SELECT ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
               note
        FROM   Notes
        ) 
SELECT  [note1] = CASE WHEN [ID] % 2 <> 0 THEN [note] ELSE NULL END,
        [note2] = CASE WHEN [ID] % 2 = 0 THEN [note] ELSE NULL END
FROM    NotesWithId;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE
@SQL VARCHAR(1000),
@COLUMN_LIST VARCHAR(200)
SET @COLUMN_LIST=(SELECT  STUFF((SELECT ',[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),NOTE ) +'] '
                        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NOTE FROM #C)Z
                         FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''))
SET @SQL=
'SELECT HI AS NOTE1 ,HELLO NOTE2  FROM 
(
SELECT NOTE AS NOTE FROM #C
)B
PIVOT
(
MIN(B.NOTE)   FOR B.NOTE IN ('+@COLUMN_LIST+')
)A'
SELECT @SQL
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select max(note) as note1, min(note) as note2
from t;
```